# Trying to define a model class on top of PDO and failing big time

Tags: php, oop, pdo, php-5.3

I'm trying to build a small, seemingly simple app in pure php (can't use any framework or fancy tools such as orms).

I got started by defining object representing my models. My idea is to have a `Model` base class, which would hold a static pdo instance to access the database, and two "concrete" model classes inheriting from it and implementing the custom method they'll need.

Well, boy am i rusty in PHP. It's also the first time i'm doing actual oop with it (i've done enough of it in other languages (C# and python, mainly) to understand how it's supposed to work, but some subtleties might very well elude me.

If anyone cares to help, here's what i have so far:

```
<?php
/**
 * Base model class, handling basic db connection
 */
Class Model {

    protected static $db;

    public static function initDb() {
        self::$db = new PDO(DB_CONNECTION_STRING, DB_USER, DB_PSWD);
    }

    protected function _prepare_request($sqlstmnt) {
        return self::$db->prepare($sqlstmnt);
    }

}

Model::initDb();

/**
 * Model class for Category objects
 **/
Class Categorie extends Model {

    private $request_getSingle = NULL;

    public function __contruct() {
        $this->request_getSingle = $this->_prepare_request(
            "SELECT * FROM categorie WHERE cat_id = :id;"
        );
    }   

    public function getById($id) {
        $poop = $this->request_getSingle->execute(array(':id' => $id));
        $res = $poop->fecthAll();
        print_r($res);
    }

}

// Debug tests:
$c = new Categorie();
var_dump($c);
$c->getById('1');
print_r($c);
echo 'done';
?>
```

Seems like my query objects are not initialized properly - Here's what i get when i run that silly debug code:

```
object(Categorie)#3 (1) { ["request_getSingle":"Categorie":private]=> NULL } 
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/raphi/dev/naoned-test/models/categories.php on line 18 
Call Stack: 
    0.0003 648192 1. {main}() /home/raphi/dev/naoned-test/models/categories.php:0 
    0.0011 661784 2. Categorie->getById() /home/raphi/dev/naoned-test/models/categories.php:27
```

I have NO idea what exactly is going wrong. I might be using static variables wrong, or miss something about how PDO works.

Hope that's clear enough, and thank to anyone willing to help (there might be somme silly errors here and there caused by helpless hacking around).

**EDIT:**
After hacking around, turns out that if i call the PDO prepare, execute, etc... methods within `getById`, everything works fine. But why can't i keep the prepared SQL statement as an instance variable ? Having to call `prepare` each time i want to access it seems to defeat its purpose...

**EDIT:**
Well... This seems fixed, but i still don't understand.
I've replaced my `request_getSingle` variable by an array, which contains several prepared statements (which is what i planned to do eventually anyway...) and everything works fine.

I don't get it. If i store them in an array, they can be accessed from the class's other methods, but if i store them as regular attributes, they can't ?

If anyone has some idea of what's going on, i'm still interested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Class Model extends PDO {
```

I have a similar class that writes custom functions on top of PDO. I think you are trying to do something similar here. This is how the initial code in my class looks like:

```
class MySQLDB extends PDO{
    public function __construct($dsn, $user="", $pass="") {
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try {
            parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $err) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

After you do that, you should be able to use all the PDO functions through this class.

Comment: I see what you mean. It still doesn't explain why i can't seem to use a static PDO instance, though :( Also, i've tried going your why, and i'm still stuck. Instanciating a `Categorie` object and calling its prepare method works, but i get the same error if i try to call it inernally with `$this->prepare('SOME SQL');`

Comment: is there any specific error message that you are getting? Is that same as before? Can you post it here?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/raphi/dev/naoned-test/models/categories.php on line 39

Comment: var_dumping the whole object before calling the method gives me `object(Categorie)#3 (1) { ["sth_getSingle":"Categorie":private]=> NULL } `  So something's going wrong when i call PDO->prepare from within the subclass.

Comment: I am getting that too.

Comment: public function __contruct() { needs to be changed to
public function __contsruct() { 
[spelling error]
because of that, the control is not going into the constructor and you are getting that error. I am getting another error in a different function though.

Comment: Oh god... I'm so used to having things blowup EXPLICITELY in cases like this that i would never have bothered to check that one o_O Must have fixed it by chance without even noticing...  There were a few other mistakes in the original source i posted which got fixed, yeah. Thanks a lot for pointing this out anyway ;)

Comment: its OK. It happens sometime to me too. Even after fixing the __construct() error, I am getting this error though:
Fatal error: Call to a member function fecthAll() on a non-object in line 37

Comment: Yeah, i was misusing the PDO object, the script crashed before those so i didn't notice. Fix is something like `$this->query...->execute(array(...)); return $this->query...->fetch();`

Comment: yeah I got that to work too:
public function getById($id) {
    $this->request_getSingle->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $res = $this->request_getSingle->fetchAll();
    print_r($res);
}